# YUI Editor: <p> instead <br> on linebreak?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yui, richtextbox, richtextediting

How do I tell the YUI-Editor to enclose all text into `<p></p>` and use `<p></p>` instead of `<br>` if the user issues a linebreak?

Here comes an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

Instead of this:

```
The quick brown fox<br>jumps over the lazy dog
```

I would like to have this:

```
<p><p>The quick brown fox</p><p>jumps over the lazy dog</p></p>
```

Any idea how to do this besides parsing the whole html before saving it and finding-replacing the tags?

**Update**:
I just noticed, that the YUI Editor automagically issues `<p></p>` on linebreaks if the whole text is enclosed in `<p></p>`. In other words, the question would be:

> How do I tell the YUI Editor to
>   enclose the whole text in the textarea
>   with `<p></p>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want the "ptags" configuration option:

```
var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('msgpost', {
    height: '300px',
    width: '522px',
    dompath: true, //Turns on the bar at the bottom
    animate: true, //Animates the opening, closing and moving of Editor windows
    ptags: true
});
myEditor.render();
```

As documented [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html#config_ptags).

Comment: Though...if I delete the text in the textbox and paste a new one, it doesn't automatically enclose all of it with "ptags". Any idea how to do this? Pasted text should by default be in one big "ptag".

Comment: Can't you just check the when you get the text out that it has "<p><p>" at the front and if it doesn't enclose the text with your extra p tags ?

Comment: Yes, but I need to do this before the user submits the text, so my CSS magic works. I could do this using javascript, but I hoped there would be a way to avoid javascript coding (the whole implementation is made on rails using the yui_editor plugin).